# html start tag missing greater-than char

Tags: html, tags

Working my way through this tutorial [node-express-mongo primer](http://mherman.org/blog/2015/08/24/node-express-swig-mongo-primer/#.VhBDWd8qeCx)

At one point is the following tag

```
<li><a href="superhero/{{superhero.id}}"</a>{{superhero.name}}</li>
```

There is no "closing" greater-than char for the anchor's start tag.
But it works as intended.

Now I can adjust the above to create an identical looking link, but with a complete start tag:

```
<li><a href="superhero/{{superhero.id}}">{{superhero.name}}</a></li>
```

However I'm new at web design and feel like I'm missing some rules somewhere. Is this common practice and where would I find this kind of information? To me it feels awkard not seeing the tag completed.

Or maybe the browser is just forgiving and this is not a common practice?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As there is no ending bracket for the tag, the `</a` is interpreted as garbage inside the tag and the `>` after it ends the starting tag. You get a starting tag without an ending tag.

The browser then figures out that the anchor tag has to end before closing the list item tag.

You should not rely on the browser implicitly closing your tags, as browsers might react differently to incorrect markup. In this specific case it's likely that browsers react the same, but in other cases they may choose to interpret the code differently, for example placing elements in a different order than you expected.

Comment: Ah. I see. Makes sense.  Thank you!